# How to set values inside the enum directly from the properties file key?

Tags: java, enums, properties-file

I have been trying to load string values by inserting the keys from properties file inside the enum constructor. But instead of setting the values, it's setting the keys only.

My errorcodes.properties have this content

`error.id.required.message=Id is required to get the details. error.id.required.code=110`

and enum file is like this:

```
`public enum ErrorCodes {
  ID_REQUIRED("error.id.required.message",
      "error.id.required.code"),
  ID_INVALID("error.id.invalid.message",
      "error.id.invalid.code");

  private final String msg;
  private final String code;

  private ErrorCodes(String msg, String code) {
    this.msg = msg;
    this.code = code;
  }

  public String getMsg() {
    return msg;
  }

  public String getCode() {
    return code;
  }
}`
```

So I created an exception which would take one of the above defined enum as an argument and throw a custom exception with message as "Id is required to get the details." and the code as "110".

e.g., `throw new CustomException(ErrorCodes.ID_REQUIRED)`

Instead the response came as

```
"errorCode": "error.id.required.code"
"errorMessage": "error.id.required.message"
```

Please help!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In general there's no good idea to use `Enum` like this. Remember, that enum's constant is singleton, therefore you can't use this like this.

I think it's better to have separate class, where you can encapsulate this logic:

- Read property file
- Get an `Enum` and retrieve only related data from the file
- Declare two `Map` to save `message` and `code` by `ErrorCode`
- Getters to retreive `message` and `code` by `ErrorCode`
- `ErrorCode` and `ErrorCodeStore` should be in the same package

This is an enum `ErrorCode`:

```java
@lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
public enum ErrorCode {

    ID_REQUIRED("error.id.required.message", "error.id.required.code"),
    ID_INVALID("error.id.invalid.message", "error.id.invalid.code");

    final String message;
    final String code;

    public final String getMessage() {
        return ErrorCodeStore.getInstance().getValue(message);
    }

    public final String getCode() {
        return ErrorCodeStore.getInstance().getValue(code);
    }

}
```

This is `ErrorCodeStore`:

```java
@lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
final class ErrorCodeStore {

    private static ErrorCodeStore instance;

    public static ErrorCodeStore getInstance() {
        if (instance == null)
            throw new RuntimeException("ErrorCodeStore instance should be"
                                               + " initialized");
        return instance;
    }

    private final Properties properties;

    // InputStream should be explicitly closed
    public static ErrorCodeStore initFrom(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(in);

        return instance = new ErrorCodeStore(properties);
    }

    String getValue(String key) {
        return properties.getProperty(key, key);
    }

}
```

**Demo**

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ErrorCodeStore.initFrom(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/errorcodes.properties"));
    System.out.println(ErrorCode.ID_REQUIRED.getMessage()); // Id is required to get the details.
    System.out.println(ErrorCode.ID_REQUIRED.getCode());    // 110
    System.out.println(ErrorCode.ID_INVALID.getMessage());  // error.id.invalid.message
    System.out.println(ErrorCode.ID_INVALID.getCode());     // error.id.invalid.code
}
```

Comment: enums _are_ classes. An enum is fine, and an enum can be set to read the property file and set things up properly. All it really needs to do is read a Properties object in, and the `getMsg()` and `getCode()` methods need to read from the properties object(s). The other answer by Ali Malek is salvagable (heading in the right direction but too far as yet to be a good answer), if you're looking for an example of what that would roughly look like.

Comment: @rzwitserloot you are not rightn. If you add reading property to the construcor, this is not good by OOP and you readit as many times, as amount of constants int the enum.

Comment: @oleg.cherednik vote up, agree that enum constants should no take any responsibility.

Comment: Nowhere did I say that you should add reading properties _to the constructor_, @oleg.cherednik. enums can have static initializer blocks.

Comment: Read the other answer by @AliMalek which shows the right strategy. The code that is intrinsically linked to the `ErrorCodes` concept is in the type `ErrorCodes` (that's good), the nature of these codes are that they are known at compile time, limited, and not extensible - i.e. an enum, and that answer works by having them _be_ an `enum`, that's good.  It reads the resource in only one time. That's good. If you want, `ErrorCodeStore` can live as private class inside `enum ErrorCodes`.